# Код выбивает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
from PIL import Image
sl={
    '1':'E:\telegrambot\1.jpg',
    '2':'E:\telegrambot\2.jpg',
    '3':'E:\telegrambot\3.jpg',
    '4':'E:\telegrambot\4.jpg',
    '5':'E:\telegrambot\5.jpg',
    '6':'E:\telegrambot\6.jpg',
    '7':'E:\telegrambot\7.jpg',
    '8':'E:\telegrambot\8.jpg',
    '9':'E:\telegrambot\9.jpg'
    }
sk ={
    '1':'текст1',
    '2':'текст2',
    '3':'текст3',
    '4':'текст4',
    '5':'текст5',
    '6':'текст6',
    '7':'текст7',
    '8':'текст8',
    '9':'текст9'        
}
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN');
def ds (message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фото', callback_data='yes')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Cлова', callback_data='no')
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Выбрать действие:', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'yes':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(sl[str(random.randint(1,9))])
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sk[str(random.randint(1,9))])  
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0
```

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки, нажав [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1364610/edit) под вопросом

Comment: @Гарри Галлер,  не знал в чём ошибка была

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, open(sl[str(random.randint(1,9))]))
    elif call.data == 'no':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sk[str(random.randint(1,9))])
```

в конце`bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, open(sl[str(random.randint(1,9))]))` я добавил 1 ")" ибо её там просто-напросто не хватало, так же в той же строчке добавил `call.` перед `message`